# [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-hooks, react-firebase-hooks

firebase error:

[image]

I am using react-hooks-firebase, with react and TypeScript, I added true to the firebase database...

[image]

**firebase.ts**:

I added '' as a solution I saw in Stack Overflow with using the way of Vite.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'import.meta.env.API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'import.meta.env.AUTH_DOMATIN',
  projectId: 'import.meta.env.PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'import.meta.env.STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'import.meta.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'import.meta.env.APP_ID',
  measurementId: 'import.meta.env.MEASUREMENT_ID'
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the HTTP error, we can see that the API key used is `import.meta.env.API_KEY` which should be your actual API key:

```
POST: https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=import.meta.env.API_KEY 400 (Bad Request)
```

Looking at your `firebaseConfig` object, we can see that each value is provided as a string instead of pulling from the `import.meta.env` object itself:

```js
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'import.meta.env.API_KEY',
  authDomain: 'import.meta.env.AUTH_DOMATIN',
  projectId: 'import.meta.env.PROJECT_ID',
  storageBucket: 'import.meta.env.STORAGE_BUCKET',
  messagingSenderId: 'import.meta.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',
  appId: 'import.meta.env.APP_ID',
  measurementId: 'import.meta.env.MEASUREMENT_ID'
};
```

should be

```js
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.AUTH_DOMATIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.MEASUREMENT_ID
};
```

**Note:** Your linter may complain that `import.meta.env` does not exist. If this is the case, you should follow the [IntelliSense for TypeScript documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript) to declare the appropriate values.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you for the great explanation of the "makes". I fixed it by adding "VITE" in front of every single variable. Thanks for the link you provided.